# Is there a built-in way to access a project's csproj file data?

Tags: c#, csproj

Or maybe access it's data via reflection somehow ?

Thanks

EDIT: I'd like to know if there's a way to do it without reading it as an XML.
Like a ms library that supports it, so it'll work for any kind of project and any kind of vs version (2005, 2008, 2010 ... ).

Comment: during execution or from visual studio?

Comment: during execution, and not by parsing it or reading it as an XML file.

Answer (score 3):

The *.csproj file is really just an XML file. You can open it just like any other XML file and treat it as such as well. Realize that any changes made to it, though, will require reloading the project.

Also, remember, there is no *.csproj file once the application is compiled/deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can open it in a text editor, or from Visual Studio

- Right click on a project
- Unload Project
- Right click on the unloaded project
- Edit project

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking the project and selecting the properties option gives you a GUI to change some of the settings in the project file. Also, when you right click a file and change it's properties it causes a change in the project file. If you want to do anything very serious, like add custom build steps, you have to do it by hand in a text editor like notepad++. It's just an XML file. If you're familiar with MSBuild the proj file has many similarities to a build script for MSBuild.